# How to plot multiple measurements from several different categories?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am a bit confused about what sort of package to use in order to plot my data which typically consists of 10 different categories (e.g. Temperatures) with 3 or 4 parallel measurements each. Here I have tried just using pandas (Trial1+2) and seaborn (Trial3).

In the end, what I would like to have is a scatterplot showing the three measurements from each category, and additionally drawing an average line through all my data (see example A and B below in figure).

I know that I can place my data in a CSV file which I can import using the PANDAS package in jupyter notebook. **Then I get to my problem;** which I think now might be related to indexing or data types? I get a lot of error that x must equal y, or that the index 'Degrees' is not defined... I will show the most successful trials below.

I have tried several things so far using this made up dataset 'Dummydata' which is very representative for the type of things I will do with my real data.

**My test CSV File:**

Its a .CSV file with four columns, where the first is the temperature, then the three next columns are the first, second and third measurement from corresponding temperature (y1, y2, y3).

```
in[]: Dummydata.to_dict()
Out[]:
    {'Degrees': {0: 0,
      1: 10,
      2: 20,
      3: 30,
      4: 40,
      5: 50,
      6: 60,
      7: 70,
      8: 80,
      9: 90},
     'y1': {0: 20, 1: 25, 2: 34, 3: 35, 4: 45, 5: 70, 6: 46, 7: 20, 8: 10, 9: 15},
     'y2': {0: 20, 1: 24, 2: 32, 3: 36, 4: 41, 5: 77, 6: 48, 7: 23, 8: 19, 9: 16},
     'y3': {0: 18, 1: 26, 2: 36, 3: 37, 4: 42, 5: 75, 6: 46, 7: 21, 8: 15, 9: 16}}
```

**Trial 1: trying to achieve a scatterplot**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Dummydata = pd.read_csv('DummyData.csv','r',delimiter=(';'), header=0)

y = ['y1','y2','y3']
x = ['Degrees']

Dummydata.plot(x,y)
```

This will give a nice line plot but also produce the UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name (??).
If I change the plot to Dummydata.plot.scatter(x,y) then I get the error: x and y must be the same size... So I know that the shape of my data is (10,4) because of 10 rows and 4 column, how can I redefine this to be okay for pandas?

**Trial 2: same thing small adjustments**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#import the .csv file, and set deliminator to ; and set the header as the first line(0)
Dummydata = pd.read_csv('DummyData.csv','r',delimiter=(';'), header = 0)
x =('Degrees')
y1 =('y1')
y2 =('y2')
y3 =('y3')


Dummydata.plot([x,y3])                       #works fine for one value, but prints y1 and y2 ?? why?
    Dummydata.plot([x,y1])                       # also works, but print out y2 and y3 ??? why?                       # also works but prints out y2 and y3 ?? why?
    Dummydata.plot([x,y])                   # get error all arrays must be same length?
Dummydata.plot.scatter([x,y])                   # many error, no plot
```

Somehow I must tell pandas that the data shape (10,4) is okay? Not sure what im doing wrong here.

**Trial 3: using seaborn and try to get a scatterplot**

I simply started to make a Factorplot, where I again came to the same problem of being able to get more than one y value onto my graph. I dont think converting this to a scatter would be hard if I just know how to add more data onto one graph.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#import the .csv file using pandas
Dummydata = pd.read_csv('DummyData.csv', 'r', delimiter=(';'))

#Checking what the file looks like
#Dummydata.head(2)

x =('Degrees')
y1 =('y1')
y2 =('y2')
y3 =('y3')
y =(['y1','y2','y3'])

Factorplot =sns.factorplot(x='Degrees',y='y1',data=Dummydata)
```

The Factor plot works fine for one dataset, however, trying to add more y value (either defining y =(['y1','y2','y3']) before or in the plotting, I get errors like:  Could not interpret input 'y'.. For instance for this input:

```
Factorplot =sns.factorplot(x='Degrees',y='y',data=Dummydata)
```

or

```
    Factorplot =sns.factorplot(x='Degrees',y=(['y1','y2','y3']),data=Dummydata) 
#Error: cannot copy sequence with size 3 to array axis with dimension 10
```

**What I would like to achieve is something like this:**, where in (A) I would like a scatterplot with a rolling mean average - and in (B) I would like to plot the average only from each category but also showing the standard deviation, and additional draw a rolling mean across each category as following:

[image]

I dont want to write my data values in manually, I want to import then using .csv file (because the datasets can become very big).

Is there something wrong with the way I am organising my csv file?

All help appreciated.

Comment: Seaborn could be of help:
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html#seaborn.lineplot

Comment: I'll look into seaborn - thanks! I

Comment: Just as a note, it would be easier for people to help you if you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Here is my favorite [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32536193/7480990) that explains how to make an MCVE in pandas.

Comment: Noted, I will try to update this question after trying out seaborn.. but for now I really have no coding, I just need an idea on where to start because I know what im doing now does not work.

Comment: Right - in making the MCVE, often times you can answer your own question. You seem to be able to read your data into Pandas and create some plots with it already, so how about showing us that?

Comment: Updated as much as I could, I think now I have basically narrowed down my problem to actually being able to have more than one y-value in the plot...

Comment: Hi, the link you posted to your data does not work, it's on your local machine. You can use `Dummydata.to_dict()` and post the output of that, that makes it very easy to reproduce your data.

Comment: Oh, great that you already have an answer, was just checking back on this :) I hope this demonstrates how useful it is to share an MCVE - makes it much easier to help you out and you did a great job writing this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute rolling statistics with `rolling`. Compute mean and standard deviation with `mean`and `std`. Plot data with `plot`. Add y-error bars with the `yerr` keyword argument.

```
data = data.set_index('Degrees').rolling(window=6).mean()
mean = data.mean(axis='columns')
std = data.std(axis='columns')

ax = mean.plot()
data.plot(style='o', ax=ax)
```

[image]

```
plt.figure()
mean.plot(yerr=std, capsize=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! is there also a way to do this with seaborn?

Comment: Just for learning purposes, I can work a bit more on it and ask a different question if I have some particular problem in the future. Thanks